# Microsoft Excel: How to invert values based on a limit?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel sheet holding four columns, each containing a number between **1** and **10**. The first two columns contain proper values, however, column three and four do not. Instead, they contain inverse values due to a mistake in data collection. I would like to invert the values once more in order to adjust for the mistake. An example would be a cell holding the value **7**, which should be **3**, as the limit is **10**. In similar fashion, the number **3** should be inverted to **7** and so forth. How would I go about in order to achieve this result for a whole column?

Comment: In a new Column E, enter `=10-C1` in E1.  Also enter `=10-D1` in F1.  Fill both of those formulas down as far as necessary.  If you want to then eliminate Columns C & D, first copy Columns E & F and choose "Paste Special...", selecting "Values" in the dialog box.  Check that the formulas are gone in E & F and that they contain only the correct data values.  Then you can delete Columns C & D.

Comment: This solved my problem. I sure feel dumb, considering how easy it was. Anyway, thank you!